# Geany: Syntax highlighting for custom filetype for SOME words

Tags: syntax-highlighting, text-editor, geany

**Geany** is a simple, fast and yet powerful text editor.
It has quite strong support for syntax highlighting for almost all kinds
of programming languages.

I was wondering how to make a customized syntax highlighting for my
special need program called "Phosim" which has the file extension `.cat`.

So far I have done this:
First I created filetype extension configuration file: `~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf`
The contents of this looks like this:

```
[Extensions]
Gnuplot=*.gp;*.gnu;*.plt;
Galfit=*.gal;
Phosim=*.cat;
[Groups]
Script=Gnuplot;Galfit;Phosim;
```

Here, I am trying to apply custom highlight to programs Gnuplot, Galfit, and Phosim. For Gnuplot and Galfit it works fine. But for Phosim I got some problems.

Then I created file definition configuration file: `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Phosim.conf`
The contents of which looks like this:

```
# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Date    : May 24, 2016
# Version : 1.0


[styling]
# Edit these in the colorscheme .conf file instead
default=default
comment=comment_line
function=keyword_1
variable=string_1,bold
label=label
userdefined=string_2
number=number_2


[keywords]
# all items must be in one line separated by space
variables=object Unrefracted_RA_deg SIM_SEED none
functions=
lables=10
userdefined=angle 30 Angle_RA 20.0 none  
numbers=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9


[lexer_properties]
nsis.uservars=1
nsis.ignorecase=1


[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=cat

# single comments, like # in this file
comment_single=#
# multiline comments
#comment_open=
#comment_close=


# This setting works only for single line comments
comment_use_indent=true

# context action command (please see Geany's main documentation for details)
 context_action_cmd=

# lexer filetype should be an existing lexer that does not use lexer_filetype itself
lexer_filetype=NSIS


[build-menu]
EX_00_LB=Execute
EX_00_CM=
EX_00_WD=
FT_00_LB=
FT_00_CM=
FT_00_WD=
FT_02_LB=
FT_02_CM=
FT_02_WD=
```

Now my example.cat looks like this:

```
# example.cat
angle 30
Angle_RA 20.0
object none

# Till now, 
# Words highlighted    : angle 30 object none
# Words not highlighted: Angle_RA 20.0
# I like them also to be highlighted!
```

I got syntax highlighting for only two words, viz., object and none.
I tried styling equal to Fortran since it has uppercase letters but it also did not work.

**How can we get the syntax highlight for the variable names which contains uppercase, lowercase, and underscore?**

For example:
I got syntax highlight for words: `object` `none`.
But, did not get syntax highlight for words: `Angle_RA` `20.0`

Also, I my numbers `0`,`1`,..,`9` are highlighted but the decimals are not highlighted. How can we highlight decimals too?

For example:
I got syntax highlight for words: `1` `1000` but, did not get syntax highlight for words: `49552.3` `180.0`

Some useful links are following:
[Make Geany recognize additional file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316547/make-geany-recognize-additional-file-extensions)
[Custom syntax highlighting in Geany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769358/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-geany)
http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#custom-filetypes
http://www.geany.org/manual/#lexer-filetype

Comment: If the fellow community have a better answer, I welcome it and will make it the accepted answer, but in the mean time,  I have posted a workaround as the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating new file definition files I added file extensions for Python and it worked for me.

For example, I wanted to custom highlight the files with extension **.icat** (If you are interested, this is instance catalog file for Phosim Software in Astronomy.)

**Drawback:** The additional words are also highlighted in python scripts (.py,.pyc,.ipy)

**Note:** If anybody posts solution that works with new file extension, `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.Phosim.conf` I would heartly welcome that.
My example.pcat file looks like this:

```
# example.pcat
Unrefracted_RA_deg 0
Unrefracted_Dec_deg 0
Unrefracted_Azimuth 0
Unrefracted_Altitude 89
Slalib_date 1994/7/19/0.298822999997
Opsim_rotskypos 0
Opsim_rottelpos 0
Opsim_moondec -90
Opsim_moonra 180
Opsim_expmjd 49552.3
Opsim_moonalt -90
Opsim_sunalt -90
Opsim_filter 2
Opsim_dist2moon 180.0
Opsim_moonphase 10.0
Opsim_obshistid 99999999
Opsim_rawseeing 0.65
SIM_SEED 1000
SIM_MINSOURCE 1
SIM_TELCONFIG 0
SIM_CAMCONFIG 1
SIM_VISTIME 15000.0
SIM_NSNAP 1
object 0 0.0 0.0 20 ../sky/sed_flat.txt 0 0 0 0 0 0 bhishan.fits 0.09 0.0 none
```

I want geany to highlight all first words with yellow color, numbers with mangenta, and the word 'none' with blue color.

First I created (or, edited if already exists) the file:

```
~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf
```

And added following stuff inside it.

```
[Extensions]
Gnuplot=*.gp;*.gnu;*.plt;
Galfit=*.gal;
Phosim=*.pcat;
Python=*.py;*.pyc;*.ipy;*.icat;*.pcat
[Groups]
Script=Gnuplot;Galfit;Phosim;Python;
```

Then, I added the additional KEYWORDS to the already existing keywords in python filetype.
For this I created (or, edited if already exists) the file:

```
~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.python
```

Now, the file `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.python` looks like this:

```
# Author  : Bhishan Poudel
# Date    : June 9, 2016
# Version : 1.0
# File    : Filetype for both python and phosim_instance_catalogs

[styling]
default=default
commentline=comment_line
number=number_1
string=string_1
character=character
word=keyword_1
triple=string_2
tripledouble=string_2
classname=type
defname=function
operator=operator
identifier=identifier_1
commentblock=comment
stringeol=string_eol
word2=keyword_2
decorator=decorator


[keywords]
# all items must be in one line
primary=and as assert break class continue def del elif else except exec finally for from global if import in is lambda not or pass print raise return try while with yield False None True  Words_after_this_are_for_Phosim_pcat_files Unrefracted_RA_deg Unrefracted_Dec_deg Unrefracted_Azimuth Unrefracted_Altitude Slalib_date Opsim_moondec Opsim_rotskypos Opsim_rottelpos Opsim_moondec Opsim_moonra Opsim_expmjd Opsim_moonalt Opsim_sunalt Opsim_filter Opsim_dist2moon Opsim_moonphase Opsim_obshistid Opsim_rawseeing SIM_SEED SIM_MINSOURCE SIM_TELCONFIG  SIM_CAMCONFIG SIM_VISTIME SIM_NSNAP object


identifiers=ArithmeticError AssertionError AttributeError BaseException BufferError BytesWarning DeprecationWarning EOFError Ellipsis EnvironmentError Exception FileNotFoundError FloatingPointError FutureWarning GeneratorExit IOError ImportError ImportWarning IndentationError IndexError KeyError KeyboardInterrupt LookupError MemoryError NameError NotImplemented NotImplementedError OSError OverflowError PendingDeprecationWarning ReferenceError RuntimeError RuntimeWarning StandardError StopIteration SyntaxError SyntaxWarning SystemError SystemExit TabError TypeError UnboundLocalError UnicodeDecodeError UnicodeEncodeError UnicodeError UnicodeTranslateError UnicodeWarning UserWarning ValueError Warning ZeroDivisionError __debug__ __doc__ __import__ __name__ __package__ abs all any apply basestring bin bool buffer bytearray bytes callable chr classmethod cmp coerce compile complex copyright credits delattr dict dir divmod enumerate eval execfile exit file filter float format frozenset getattr globals hasattr hash help hex id input int intern isinstance issubclass iter len license list locals long map max memoryview min next object oct open ord pow print property quit range raw_input reduce reload repr reversed round set setattr slice sorted staticmethod str sum super tuple type unichr unicode vars xrange zip array arange Catagorical cStringIO DataFramedate_range genfromtxt  linspace loadtxt matplotlib none numpy np pandas pd plot plt pyplot savefig scipy Series sp StringIO


[lexer_properties]
fold.comment.python=1
fold.quotes.python=1


[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=py

# the following characters are these which a "word" can contains, see documentation
wordchars=_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

# MIME type
mime_type=text/x-python
comment_single=#
comment_open="""
comment_close="""
comment_use_indent=true

# context action command (please see Geany's main documentation for details)
context_action_cmd=


[indentation]
width=4
# 0 is spaces, 1 is tabs, 2 is tab & spaces
type=0


[build_settings]
# %f will be replaced by the complete filename
# %e will be replaced by the filename without extension
# (use only one of it at one time)
compiler=python -m py_compile "%f"
run_cmd=python "%f"


[build-menu]
FT_00_LB=Execute
FT_00_CM=python %f
FT_00_WD=
FT_01_LB=
FT_01_CM=
FT_01_WD=
FT_02_LB=
FT_02_CM=
FT_02_WD=
EX_00_LB=Execute
EX_00_CM=clear; python %f
EX_00_WD=
error_regex=([^:]+):([0-9]+):([0-9:]+)? .*
EX_01_LB=
EX_01_CM=
EX_01_WD=
```

Now, I restarted the geany and I can see all the first words in yellow, numbers other color and the word 'none' is blue colored.