# Geany: Custom syntax highlight for bibtex files (*.bib)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, geany

By default *.bib files assumes the syntax highlighting of latex files in geany.
However, I wanted to change the syntax highlight of .bib files.

I created a file definition for bibtex:

```
~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetype.Bibtex.conf
```

Which looks like this:

```
# Geany Color Syntax support for Gnuplot 4.2+
# version 0.1
# April 5, 2013


[styling]
# Edit these in the colorscheme .conf file instead
default=default
comment=comment_line
stringdq=string_1
stringlq=string_2
stringrq=string_2
function=keyword_1
variable=keyword_1,bold
label=label
userdefined=keyword_2,bold
sectiondef=keyword_1
subsectiondef=keyword_1
ifdefinedef=keyword_1
macrodef=keyword_1
stringvar=string_1
number=number_1
sectiongroup=keyword_1
pageex=keyword_1
functiondef=keyword_1
commentbox=comment


[keywords]
# all items must be in one line
variables=abstract address annote author booktitle chapter contents copyright  crossref doi edition editor institution isbn issn lccn journal key keywords month note number organization pages price publisher school series title type url language volume year
userdefined=article book booklet conference inbook incollection manual masterthesis misc phdthesis proceedings techreport unpublished


[lexer_properties]
nsis.uservars=1
nsis.ignorecase=1


[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=bib

# single comments, like # in this file
comment_single=#
# multiline comments
#comment_open=
#comment_close=


# This setting works only for single line comments
comment_use_indent=true

# context action command (please see Geany's main documentation for details)
context_action_cmd=

# lexer filetype should be an existing lexer that does not use lexer_filetype itself
lexer_filetype=NSIS


[build-menu]
EX_00_LB=Execute
EX_00_CM=rm fit.log; galfit %e.gal; rm galfit.0*; open fit.log
EX_00_WD=
FT_00_LB=
FT_00_CM=
FT_00_WD=
FT_02_LB=
FT_02_CM=
FT_02_WD=
```

Then, I included file extension in the file:

```
~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf
```

Now suppose I have a sample bib file, e.g.
bibtex3.bib which looks like this:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

But still I do not see syntax highlight of .bib files.

Some related links:
http://www.geany.org/manual/0.14/#filetype-extensions
[Custom syntax highlighting in Geany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769358/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-geany)
[Make Geany recognize additional file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316547/make-geany-recognize-additional-file-extensions)

**Question:** How to custom syntax highlight .bib files in geany?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default .bib files are associated with Latex.
Change the following file:

```
~/.config/geany/filetype_extensions.conf
```

Which look like this:

```
# Filetype extension configuration file for Geany
# Insert as many items as you want, separate them with a ";".
# See Geany's main documentation for details.
[Extensions]
Abaqus=*.inp;
Abc=*.abc;*.abp;
ActionScript=*.as;
Ada=*.adb;*.ads;
Asciidoc=*.asciidoc;*.adoc;
ASM=*.asm;*.asm51;*.a51;
Batch=*.bat;*.cmd;*.nt;
CAML=*.ml;*.mli;
C=*.c;*.xpm;
C++=*.cpp;*.cxx;*.c++;*.cc;*.h;*.hpp;*.hxx;*.h++;*.hh;*.C;*.H;
Clojure=*.clj;*.cljs;*.cljc;
CUDA=*.cu;*.cuh;*.h;
C#=*.cs;
CMake=CMakeLists.txt;*.cmake;*.ctest;
COBOL=*.cob;*.cpy;*.cbl;*.cobol;
CoffeeScript=*.coffee;Cakefile;*.Cakefile;*.coffee.erb;*.iced;*.iced.erb;
Conf=*.conf;*.ini;config;*rc;*.cfg;*.desktop;*.properties;
CSS=*.css;
Cython=*.pyx;*.pxd;*.pxi;
D=*.d;*.di;
Diff=*.diff;*.patch;*.rej;
Docbook=*.docbook;
Erlang=*.erl;*.hrl;
F77=*.f;*.for;*.ftn;*.f77;*.F;*.FOR;*.FTN;*.fpp;*.FPP;
Ferite=*.fe;
Forth=*.fs;*.fth;
Fortran=*.f90;*.f95;*.f03;*.f08;*.F90;*.F95;*.F03;*.F08;
FreeBasic=*.bas;*.bi;*.vbs;
Genie=*.gs;
GLSL=*.glsl;*.frag;*.vert;
Go=*.go;
Graphviz=*.gv;*.dot;
Haskell=*.hs;*.lhs;*.hs-boot;*.lhs-boot;
Haxe=*.hx;
HTML=*.htm;*.html;*.shtml;*.hta;*.htd;*.htt;*.cfm;*.tpl;
Java=*.java;*.jsp;
Javascript=*.js;
JSON=*.json;
LaTeX=*.tex;*.sty;*.idx;*.ltx;*.latex;*.aux;
Lisp=*.lisp;
Lua=*.lua;
Make=*.mak;*.mk;GNUmakefile;makefile;Makefile;makefile.*;Makefile.*;*.make;
Markdown=*.mdml;*.markdown;*.md;*.mkd;*.mkdn;*.mdwn;*.mdown;*.mdtxt;*.mdtext;
Matlab/Octave=*.m;
NSIS=*.nsi;*.nsh;
Objective-C=*.m;*.mm;*.h;
Pascal=*.pas;*.pp;*.inc;*.dpr;*.dpk;
Perl=*.pl;*.perl;*.pm;*.agi;*.pod;
PHP=*.php;*.php3;*.php4;*.php5;*.phtml;
Po=*.po;*.pot;
Python=*.py;*.pyw;SConstruct;SConscript;wscript;
PowerShell=*.ps1;*.psm1;
reStructuredText=*.rest;*.reST;*.rst;
R=*.R;*.r;
Rust=*.rs;
Ruby=*.rb;*.rhtml;*.ruby;*.gemspec;Gemfile;rakefile;Rakefile;
Scala=*.scala;*.scl;
Sh=*.sh;configure;configure.in;configure.in.in;configure.ac;*.ksh;*.mksh;*.zsh;*.ash;*.bash;.bashrc;bash.bashrc;.bash_*;bash_*;*.m4;PKGBUILD;*profile;
SQL=*.sql;
Tcl=*.tcl;*.tk;*.wish;
Txt2tags=*.t2t;
Vala=*.vala;*.vapi;
Verilog=*.v;
VHDL=*.vhd;*.vhdl;
XML=*.xml;*.sgml;*.xsl;*.xslt;*.xsd;*.xhtml;*.xul;*.dtd;*.xtpl;*.mml;*.mathml;
YAML=*.yaml;*.yml;
Zephir=*.zep;
None=*;

# Note: restarting is required after editing groups
[Groups]
Programming=Clojure;CUDA;Cython;Genie;Scala;
Script=Graphviz;
Markup=
Misc=JSON;
None=
```

Now, make the following changes:

```
LaTeX=*.tex;*.sty;*.idx;*.ltx;*.latex;*.aux;
```

Then, new file definitions should work for bibtex files.

If this does not work :
open the required .bib file.
Document > SetFiletype > Scripting Language > Bibtex source file.